# In powershell via RDP RemoteApp, why does `start firefox` work, but `start chrome` not work?

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, rdp

If I do an RDP to the remote machine, open Powershell from the Start menu, then start Chrome, it will start up correctly, i.e., open a new window, with this command:

```
start chrome
```

I have Powershell configured as a remote app. When I log on to the RemoteApp instead, then I can enter

```
start firefox
start calc
Start-Process calc
```

and these applications all appear on the RDP client as I would expect. But

```
start chrome
```

does nothing. I don't get any errors, the window simply does not show up. Everything is up-to-date as of Oct 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell, `start` is an alias for `Start-Process`. This Cmdlet makes a
low level call to `Shell.ShellExecute` which works like this:

1. start firefox
2. Start-Process firefox
3. Start-Process firefox.exe
4. Search for firefox.exe on *PATH*
5. Search for firefox.exe on *App Paths*

So likely what has happened is that Firefox is on *App Paths* and and Chrome is
not.

[Run box special folders](https://superuser.com/a/828025)

Comment: But wouldn't I get an error if it was a matter of the executable not being found? If I run `start foo` I get an error.

Comment: I dont have Chrome, and Im not about to install it to resolve this question, even on a virtual machine. Sorry mate

Comment: No worries... thanks for trying. BTW I checked and chrome is in App Paths.